# Spring:data Cassandra How to return row data in based on offset[Number of rows] value?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, cql, datastax, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to get row data based on my offset value-
1st request offset value= (0-100) means 100
2nd request passing offset as 101-200 rows?

my repository-

```
 @Query("select * from customer_request where product_id = ?0 and receipt_period = ?1 limit ?2 ")
 List<CustomerRequest> findByProduct(String productId, String datePeriod, Integer offset);
```

How to request specific number of rows?

Can i use stmt.setFetchSize(100); something like this? If yes can you please show me how to do that?

I am using data.cassandra.version =1.3.0.RELEASE &
datastax.version>2.1.7

I am very new to this Spring-data cassandra. I updated my repository but got lot of error! Do i need to create a session with Cassandra before making query? Please advise me on my implementation as i stuck at a point.

```
 Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("select * from customer_request where product_id = ?0 and receipt_period = ?1");
 List<CustomerRequest> findByProductIdAndReceiptPeriod(String productId, String receiptPeriod);

 stmt.setFetchSize(100)
 ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);

 Iterator<Row> iter = rs.iterator();
 {
  rs.fetchMoreResults();
  Row row = iter.next();
 } while (!rs.isFullyFetched())
```

Any help or suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version you are using but you can look at using paging in the Java Driver.  Look at the link below to see how:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/paging/

Comment: Hi, The link u shared here , Can you please tell me whtat i need t pass here-
String requestedPage = extractPagingStateStringFromURL();
??